# Ordering Host Groups Page on Nagios

Tags: nagios

We are monitoring quite a lot of devices using Nagios, and the host group page page is starting to get a bit cluttered. 
Does any one know of a way to force the order of the groups on that page, the main reason being i want the groups with the most hosts to appear first as i think the page will look a bit cleaner

Thanks
Luke

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to force the ordering is to prepend a number to each group name to force the sorting order. I recommend not worrying about ordering, though. It sounds like you are getting more hosts than you can check with one of the pages. I recommend using the "service problems" or "host problems" views to only show what's wrong. that is a much easier way to view things. Besides, you don't care about what's working, only what's broken.